# Difference between Arduino.cc and Arduino.org

Tags: hardware

Recently I have noticed that there are two arduino sites, arduino.cc and arduino.org.  They both have the Arduino logo and both sell what seems to be official Arduino boards. Also, arduino.org came out with the Arduino Zero board first. What is the deal here? Has Arduino partnered with another site? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Does arduino llc or .cc endorse products that are labeled such as UNO, but were made by others who are selling experiment kits with things like MAX7219 and 5461BS anode LED digit displays that are not compatible with each other? Or is this one of the issues that the arduino group together is trying to decide what to do with? The kit work, but some of the stuff isn't compatible with each other, according to the tutorials on the web.

Comment: ok understand the situation. QUestion is I have a Arduino motor shield with arduino.org stamped on it. I have a schematic for a board that was downloaded from the Arduino.cc web site. The two do not match and the .org board I have is not working the way it should. Anyone have any experience with this situation?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The short of it is that there was a falling out within the Arduino people and now [there are two groups laying claim to the "Arduino" name.](http://hackaday.com/2015/03/28/arduino-srl-to-distributors-were-the-real-arduino/)

Arduino LLC runs arduino.cc. They are the steward of the Arduino IDE and libraries and own the "Arduino" trademark in the United States, and also owns the "Genuino" trademark outside of the United States. Arduino SRL (fka Smart Projects SRL) is the company that assembles(assembled) the majority of Arduino boards for Arduino LLC, runs arduino.org, and owns the "Arduino" trademark inside Italy and all of the other countries they have registered the "Arduino" trademark.

Arduino SRL recently decided that they are no longer beholden to Arduino LLC and has stopped paying licensing fees for using the Arduino name. Whether this is justified or not has not been fully tested in court yet.

Comment: Story morality: don't make business with your friends, or do it properly, as you would with anybody else. Sad but true.

Comment: This is a sum up from Massimo Banzi: http://makezine.com/2015/03/19/massimo-banzi-fighting-for-arduino/

Comment: "are the creator of the Arduino IDE"  is too kind, and not quite factual. They are the original people who took Wiring project, marketed it better, then pretended like Wiring never existed. Of course the Wiring people did the same from the Processing project for the IDE.

Comment: They have the exact same logo. That's weird. @user6569 I don't think they pretended like it never existed or that you're giving them credit for their tons of original contributions/content. They did create the Arduino IDE. Like every other piece of software, literature, math, and science, it stands on the shoulders of its predecessors.

Answer (score 14):

This article can explain it better than I could paraphrase:
http://hackaday.com/2015/02/25/arduino-v-arduino/

Relevant excerpt:

> Arduino LLC [***arduino.cc***] is the company founded by Massimo Banzi, David Cuartielles, David Mellis, Tom Igoe and Gianluca Martino in 2009 and is the owner of the Arduino trademark and gave us the designs, software, and community support that’s gotten the Arduino where it is. The boards were manufactured by a spinoff company, Smart Projects Srl, founded by the same Gianluca Martino. So far, so good.
>
> Things got ugly in November when Martino ... renamed Smart Projects to Arduino Srl and registered ***arduino.org***
>
> According to this [Italian Wired article](http://www.wired.it/gadget/computer/2015/02/12/arduino-nel-caos-situazione/), the cause of the split is that Banzi and the other three wanted to internationalize the brand and license production to other firms freely, while Martino ... [wanted] to list on the stock market and keep all production strictly in the Italian factory.

Answer (score 10):

Please take a look at [The Untold History of Arduino](http://arduinohistory.github.io).

Answer (score 8):

Update on the situation: on October 1st, 2016 a blog post at arduino.cc "[Two Arduinos become one](https://blog.arduino.cc/2016/10/01/two-arduinos-become-one-2/)" announced that an agreement was found between arduino.cc and arduino.org. Two key points:

- the creation of a foundation
- the creation of a holding.

About the holding:

> At the end of 2016, the newly created “Arduino Holding” will become the single point of contact for the wholesale distribution of all current and future products, and will continue to bring tremendous innovations to the market.

About the foundation:

> In addition, Arduino will form a not-for-profit “Arduino Foundation” responsible for maintaining the open-source Arduino desktop IDE, and continuing to foster the open-source movement by providing support for a variety of scholarships, community and developer initiatives.

Answer (score 1):

[arduino.org](http://www.arduino.org) is not only boards assembler, but is also who designs and engineers the arduino boards. They own the arduino trademark all over the world, except the USA, therefore [arduino.cc](http://www.arduino.cc) owns the trademark only in the USA.

Comment: No; arduino.cc designs the boards and owns the tradmark everywhere except Italy.  arduino.org justmanufactures the boards (and owns the trademark in Italy) and recently forked Arduino's GitHub repo, registered the domain arduino.org, and is now pretending that they are the only ones who design and make Arduinos and that arduino.cc is an impostor.

Comment: @NobodyNada I'm sorry but you are wrong about the boards manufacturing. [arduino srl or arduino.org](http://arduino.org) came from Smart Projects, and Smart Projects is the company who always designs and engineers arduino boards.

Comment: .org owns the trademark all over the world except USA, just take a look at [arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc) web site and you can see _Arduino Only USA_ and _Genuino Outside USA_.

I never heard that arduino.org said that .cc is an impostor on the contrary .org always thanks to arudino project founders for their work. 

often people see only what they want to see and say things influencing people. (sorry for this last _non-technical_ line but I have read around the web a lot of things that are untrue and unfounded accusations)

Comment: @ThomasCeleron But still both could have instead improved Wiring.