# Did I break my new Arduino Leonardo Eth by restarting it?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, uploading, usb

I just bought a new Arduino Leonardo Eth, and, it was working perfectly.

I probably uploaded about 30 different sketches, and it did everything as expected.

The basic sketch was using the fade demo on pin 9 to ground with a LED attached.

I was then curious on how long the unit takes to restart, so, I unplugged the USB and put it back in.

When it started back up, the LED was on solid. I then restarted it again, and I honestly can't remember the state of it.

When I plug it in, it gets detected in the Arduino application and I see the port, but, after about 20 seconds, I get a popup on Windows saying about a malfunctioning USB device.

Pressing reset on the Arduino or unplugging/plugging it back does the same - I get about 20 seconds, and then it "goes bad".

Even if I am real quick in the IDE, or press restart after compiling/before upload, it just hangs.

I'm really annoyed with myself if I did break it, but, I'm not really sure what else I could have done differently... after all, there isn't an off switch.

Does anyone know what I have done, and, is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Can you communicate with it via ISP?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I just read another post about bricked Arduinos, and I am going to give that a shot... Honestly, this is my first official arduino device - I have purchased a few low end Arduino Micro compatible units, but, I am not sure that they have the ISP function... This is my first experience with arduino/electronics, and I do feel a little out of my depth! ... I was hoping there is a certain combination of restart button pushes to factory reset or similar! I'm traveling at the moment, but will try again normally and look at ISP when I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use my [board detector](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) sketch on one of your other Arduinos to check out the problem board.

See also [Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board)

Also my [bootloader uploader](http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader) sketch will reflash bootloaders on quite a few devices. I'm assuming that the "Arduino Leonardo Eth" has the same bootloader as the Leonardo.

Hmmm - I see that the "Arduino Leonardo Eth" is from Arduino.org, not Arduino.cc. The bootloader is probably slightly different. I'm really not an expert on what those boards use.

---

Before worrying too much, try the approach of holding down Reset and then uploading a sketch, letting go of Reset as the sketch starts to actually upload.

---

*Comment by William Hilsum*

> I didn't realise there was a difference between .org and .cc, and, I guess by using the leonardo template from .cc, I broke "something". The moment I downloaded the IDE from .org, & uploaded with the eth template , it worked flawlessly. I guess there are some changes between leonardo and leonardo eth. I wanted an arduino with ethernet, so I didn't need a separate shield. No idea if I picked the right "side" after reading all the crap with cc vs org!

That is very annoying that the split of the Arduino camps now produces a support nightmare for people who just want to use their virtually identical products, but have to go through this.

Thanks for the update.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, what's the difference between Arduino.org and Arduino.cc? The Leonardo Eth was from a trusted supplier (Farnell) and I didn't know there was a difference here! I thought it was just one was a community and one was the company... Anyway, as for the "cheap" Arduinos, I just bought them from eBay and have never actually used them, ... Being honest, I'm not even really sure how to right now/there is only headers/no pins, so, I have to look in to that when I have more time! I'll give the reset thing a try though. Thank you....

Comment: It's worth saying, I have a theory... I read from the Arduino troubleshooting page that it doesn't auto start if it gets a signal - I am wondering if the first time I connected, it was simply "empty" and worked, the second time, my machine/vmware/something intercepted the call and tried to do something causing it to pause. This doesn't explain why it gets detected and disconnected straight after uploading though.

Comment: The Leonardo presents as a USB device initially so you can upload a sketch to it. After a certain time (mine took around 9 seconds) it exits the bootloader, and that USB device "goes away". Then it runs your sketch. If your sketch does not open Serial, a keyboard or mouse, then it is no longer a USB device. So this is expected behaviour.

Comment: `what's the difference between Arduino.org and Arduino.cc` - various of the original Arduino founders have had a dispute about who owns the "Arduino" name. See, for example: [Arduino Wars: Group Splits, Competing Products Revealed?](http://makezine.com/2015/03/06/arduino-vs-arduino/)

Comment: Thanks so much, and found a really good answer on here shortly after writing that... I used the Arduino download from cc, I used Leonardo as the base... I just downloaded it from .org and now have the Leonardo eth template - I am guessing that as much as it worked, it may not have done a lot of good! I swear the .cc download only had ~2 drivers, the .org one needed around 10 - I hope it hasn't screwed anything up on my pc...

Comment: Please let us know how this turns out, so that the question may eventually have an answer that will help other people. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a bloody USB cable when I need one :( Guess I'm going to have to wait to do this at work! I certainly will share back!

Comment: This isn't exactly the correct answer, but, you pushed me on to the correct thing, so, if you can modify/add the following, it may help others... I didn't realise there was a difference between .org and .cc, and, I guess by using the leonardo template from .cc, I broke "something". The moment I downloaded the IDE from .org, & uploaded with the eth template , it worked flawlessly. I guess there are some changes between leonardo and leonardo eth. I wanted an arduino with ethernet, so I didn't need a separate shield. No idea if I picked the right "side" after reading all the crap with cc vs org!

Comment: I added your remarks for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: [Difference between Arduino.cc and Arduino.org](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11824/difference-between-arduino-cc-and-arduino-org)